# How to solve the conflict with the color of dark solarized and some output?

Tags: vim, mocha.js, color-scheme, pm2, iterm2

I really like the [solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) and use it as the color scheme of my iTerm and Vim.

But recentlly, I start using Node.js. The problem has been bothering me for weeks.

The color of the result of [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) and [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) seems the same the background of dark cheme,

I do not want to change to other color scheme.

So what should I do?

Thanks!!

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Solarized is [a very poorly designed colorscheme](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/802). You should switch to something less popular and more dependable.

Answer (score 1):

Finally the setting of Contrast of iTerms fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

[This patch](https://github.com/mbadolato/iTerm2-Color-Schemes/blob/master/schemes/Solarized%20Dark%20-%20Patched.itermcolors) from [iTerm2 Color Schemes](https://github.com/mbadolato/iTerm2-Color-Schemes) leaves the rest of the Solarized Dark theme unchanged while patching the unfortunate issue with the background being set to bright-black.

Answer (score 0):

If someone have the same problem, please use this [patch](https://gist.github.com/heisters/1015503) for solarized.